# How to pass a group value in inventory file to jinja2 template file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, yaml, jinja2

I have an inventory file named ***hospital.inventory*** and it contains following group with a single value.

```
[dockerSwarmManager]
hp2-3.mydomain.com
```

Then I have a file name ***security.json.j2*** inside the folder call ***templates***. In there I want to refer above mentioned value in below placeholder.

```
"wellKnownUrl": "https://_placeholder_value_/my-configuration",
```

**Is there any direct way of doing that?**

As an alternative, how I did was declare a variable in ***main.yml*** file inside ***defaults*** directory and use it.

```
swarm_hostname: "\
   {% for host in groups['dockerSwarmManager'] -%}\
   {{host}}\
   {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif -%}\
   {%- endfor %}"
```

I don't think it's nice to use a loop just to extract a single value from a group inside the inventory file even though I get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely certain that the group only contains a single value, you can use the [`first()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#first) filter on the variable to get the first element from the list:

```jinja2
swarm_hostname: "{{ groups['dockerSwarmManager'] | first }}"
```

If it is possible that there are multiple hosts you could also use [`join()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join):

```jinja2
swarm_hostname: "{{ groups['dockerSwarmManager'] | join(',') }}"
```

This would create a comma separated list, which I assume would be acceptable from your example.

And of course, this also works directly in your JSON template:

```json
"wellKnownUrl": "https://{{ groups['dockerSwarmManager'] | first }}/my-configuration",
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an Ansible "[magic variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables)", specifically "inventory_hostname". You can use it in a jinja2 template like this, using the jinja2 'double brace' variable style:

```
"wellKnownUrl": "https://{{ inventory_hostname }}/my-configuration",
```

This template line will be resolved to the following string:

```
"wellKnownUrl": "https://hp2-3.mydomain.com/my-configuration",
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case this does not work. The reason is, I'm running this script in a cluster (10.16.0.22/23/24) only one time. If I explain more, this script will run on the host 10.16.0.22 but docker swarm recide on 10.16.0.24 Therefor when I use `inventory_hostname` magic variable it will consider the hostname of 22 server.